# How to store Huffman tree in file

Tags: c++, huffman-code

I'm looking for a convenient way to store Huffman tree inside the file for further reading and decoding. Here is my Node structure:

```
struct Node
{
    char ch;
    int freq;
    Node *left, *right;

    Node(char symbol, int frequency, Node *left_Node, Node *right_Node) : ch(symbol),
                                                                          freq(frequency),
                                                                          left(left_Node),
                                                                          right(right_Node){};
};
```

I'm using pointers, so I'm not sure about how to store it.
Here is the way how I'm building the tree:

```
void buildTree(std::priority_queue<Node *, std::vector<Node *>, comp> &pq, std::multimap<int, char> &freqsTable)
{

    for (auto pair : freqsTable)
    {
        Node *node = new Node(pair.second, pair.first, nullptr, nullptr);
        pq.push(node);
    }

    while (pq.size() != 1)
    {
        Node *left = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        Node *right = pq.top();
        pq.pop();

        int freqsSum = left->freq + right->freq;
        Node *node = new Node('\0', freqsSum, left, right);
        pq.push(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: One obvious choice would be to replace the pointers with offsets into the file. You'll probably also want to precede the content from each node with something like the number of items coming from that node, so as you read it, you'll know how much to read back in to put into a node's priority queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traverse the tree recursively. At each node, send a 0 bit. At each leaf (pointers are `nullptr`), send a 1 bit, followed by the eight bits of the character.

On the other end, read a bit, make a new node if it's a zero. If it's a 1, make a leaf with the next eight bits as a character. Proceed to the next empty pointer. The tree will naturally complete, so there is no need for an end marker in the description.

Comment: So if I'm going to store a tree and my encoded data right after it how should I know if it is a last leaf and there is a data right after it?

Comment: "The tree will naturally complete, so there is no need for an end marker in the description." When you run out of things to fill in, the tree is done. The next bit is your encoded data.